# Ebay trading API - Where's the postage?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm using the Ebay trading API to get the inventory of a user.

I'm using GetSellerList() with granularity = fine, then i iterate through the ItemTypeCollection for each ItemType.
All the information i need is there except the postage.

The products do have postage on them of £7.50 but this is nowhere in the ItemType?

Any ideas how to find/get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found it lurking way deep down here:

```
myItemTypeCollection[x].ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions[x].ShippingServiceCost.Value
```

Please see here for the nuts and bolts of how to get the seller list from eBay: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

After you have called GetSellerList the below code should get the postage, i have only targeted the RoyalMail shipping service in this but if you inspect the object you'll see other options:

```
//get the seller list from EBay
ItemTypeCollection itemLists = apiGetSellerList.GetSellerList();  

//loop through the itemTypeCollection to get each item
 foreach (ItemType oItem in itemLists)
                {

                   foreach (ShippingServiceOptionsType shipType in oItem.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions)
                        {
                            ////loop through the various shipping options
                            switch (shipType.ShippingService)
                            {
                                case "UK_RoyalMailSecondClassStandard":
                                    //this is the standard postage so add this
                                    addProduct.DeliveryStandard = (decimal)shipType.ShippingServiceCost.Value;
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
}
```